# How to format a number with spanish thousand grouping in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, locale

I need to format a number with Spanish thousand separators (points instead of commas). Using locale, I can get the separators for English:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
'en_US'
>>> print(locale.format("%d", 10000000, grouping=True))
10,000,000
```

However, if I try to obtain the Spanish separators, it doesn't work:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES')
'es_ES'
>>> print(locale.format("%d", 10000000, grouping=True))
10000000
```

Any ideas on how to obtain the expected result? (10.000.000). I am using python 3.4.

Comment: This is probably prevented because `10.000.000` isn't a valid floating point number, which is how it would be interpreted. Your best best is to convert it to a string and add the separators yourself.

Comment: Thanks. The returning value of locale.format is a string (not a float). Thus, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `es_ES` numeric formatting does not include a thousands separator. The monetary formatting does, however:

```
In [16]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES')
In [17]: print(locale.format('%d', 10000000, grouping=True, monetary=True))
10.000.000
```

You can get more information by calling `locale.localeconv()`:

```
In [18]: locale.localeconv()
Out[18]: 
{'currency_symbol': 'Eu',
 'decimal_point': ',',
 'frac_digits': 2,
 'grouping': [127],
 'int_curr_symbol': 'EUR ',
 'int_frac_digits': 2,
 'mon_decimal_point': ',',
 'mon_grouping': [3, 3, 0],
 'mon_thousands_sep': '.',     # <----- NB
 'n_cs_precedes': 0,
 'n_sep_by_space': 1,
 'n_sign_posn': 1,
 'negative_sign': '-',
 'p_cs_precedes': 0,
 'p_sep_by_space': 1,
 'p_sign_posn': 1,
 'positive_sign': '',
 'thousands_sep': ''}         # <----- NB
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The monetary formatting worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried this in Python 2.7 (in Windows), and it seemed to work, but my locale setting was a bit different:

```
>>>locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'esp_esp')
'Spanish_Spain.1252'
>>>print(locale.format('%d', 10000000, grouping=True))
10.000.000
```

Which Python version are you using? (this may not be an answer, but I'm unable to use comments . . . sorry!)

Comment: Thanks! I am using Python 3.4. When trying your solution I get: 'locale.Error: unsupported locale setting'